# JavaScript extend Array and add methods to child protype?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a js class that resembles simple music playlist (Array). I want to instantiate this playlist with IDs, each ID being a track ID in my database. I have interface like this:

```
function Playlist() {
    Playlist.prototype.current = 0;
    Playlist.prototype.prev = function() {
        if (this.current-1 < 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return this[--this.current];
    };
    Playlist.prototype.next = function() {
        if (this.current+1 >= this.length) { // length is index + 1
            return null;
        }
        return this[++this.current];
    };
    Playlist.prototype.seek = function(id) {
        for (i in this) {
            if (this[i] == id) {
                this.current = parseInt(i);
                return i;
            }
        }

        return false;
    };
    Playlist.prototype.getCurrent() {
            return this.current;
    };
};
```

The code above DOES NOT do what I want, because I imagine it as `class` that has it's method defined, that can be instantiated like this:

```
var newPlaylist = Playlist(2,3,5,10/* those are my ids */);
```

And currently the only way I've found is something like:

```
Playlist.prototype = new Array(2, 3, 5, 10/* those are my ids */);
```

Which does not make any sense since it can be instantiated as different objects. Any ideas are very welcome!

Comment: a) prototype methods are not to be inside the constructor b) [`Array` can not properly be subclassed](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you [cannot subclass `Array`](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array), you should build wrapper objects with your `Playlist` constructor:

```
Playlist = (function() {
    function Playlist(list) {
        this.list = list || [];
    }

    Playlist.prototype.current = 0;
    Playlist.prototype.prev = function() {
        if (this.current <= 0)
            return null;
        return this.list[--this.current];
    };
    Playlist.prototype.next = function() {
        if (this.current+1 >= this.length)
            return null;
        return this.list[++this.current];
    };
    Playlist.prototype.seek = function(id) {
        return this.list.indexOf(id);
    };

    return Playlist;
})();
```

Usage:

```
var newPlaylist = new Playlist([2,3,5,10]);
```

Comment: The only thing that I did not like is that I can not have those definitions as single unit (function). Probably thats the best I could get with JS.

Comment: Have a look at the module pattern for building code in "units".

Comment: I read this article: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth still, I'm not quite sure how the above code would look like implemented using this. I know it's quite too much but would you be so kind to show me the same example with the module pattern? Thanks a ton!

Comment: There's not much in here (as you don't really need it), but I've adapted the answer to show you the code sample.

Answer (score 2):

Best way - nested array;

```
function Playlist() {
    this.current = 0;
    this.list = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);;
};

Playlist.prototype.prev = function() {
    if (this.current-1 < 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return this.list[--this.current];
};
Playlist.prototype.next = function() {
    if (this.current+1 >= this.list.length) { // length is index + 1
        return null;
    }
    return this.list[++this.current];
};
Playlist.prototype.getCurrent = function() {
    return this.current;
};

var newPlaylist = new Playlist(2,3,5,10/* those are my ids */);
```

But you can't use list[i] to get element by index, but you just need add at() method to your class that provide similar functionality

```
PlayList.prototype.at(i) {
    return this.list[i];
}
```